# how to set the selected listview item as header for contextmenu?

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have found several posts related with what I am posting but none of them tell me how to do it with little complex listview populated from database. This is how I am populating my listview:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
    String[] from = { "sender", "subject", "file_name" };
    int[] to = { R.id.sender, R.id.subject, R.id.file_name };
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),mylist,
            R.layout.list_item,from,to);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

so far the code is working fine that is listview is getting populated as expected now on long click I am displaying context menu like:

```
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
      if (v.getId()==R.id.mylistview) 
      {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) 
        {
          menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
      }
    }
```

now I want to set R.id.sender as the header of context menu how to do it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Later found it myself:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
    HashMap<String , String>h=new HashMap<String, String>();
      if (v.getId()==R.id.mylistview) 
      {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;

        String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu);
        h=(HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(info.position);
        String s=h.get("sender");
                menu.setHeaderTitle(s);
        for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) 
        {
          menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
      }
    }
```